# Haskell problem

Tags: haskell

I'm stuck on this exercise. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

A function takeS takes a list of pairs and compares first elements of pairs. If they are not equal, the function returns that list of pairs. If they are equal, that means they have a conflict. The function will delete either one of these two pairs and returns the list with no conflict pairs. If the returning list still has some conflict pairs, the function recursively calls itself until there are no conflict pairs.

```
takeS :: [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)]
```

Example: `takeS [("a",1),("b",2),("b",3),("c",4),("c",5)]` will return 
`[("a",1),("b",2),("c",4)]` since there are 2 conflict pairs: `("b",2)`, `("b",3)` and `("c",4)`, `("c",5)`.

Comment: What did you try so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I think the wording is confusing: perhaps you should say "compares the first elements of pairs of pairs"?

Comment: Is the list sorted so that you only have to compare adjacent pairs of pairs? (Sorry about the double comment, but these are pretty distinct.)

Comment: This is what I have so far:                                    takeS [(a1,b1),(a2,b2)] 
|a1 == a2 = [(a1,b1)]
|a1 /= a2 = [(a1,b1),(a2,b2)]
but it only takes 2 pairs and the function isn't recursive.
And sorry for the confusion. The list isn't sorted though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Data.List (nubBy)

takeS :: Eq a => [(a, b)] -> [(a, b)]
takeS = nubBy $ \(x, _) (y, _) -> x == y
```

If you don't want to import anything, you can define `nubBy` yourself; here's one possible implementation (may be less efficient than the official version):

```
-- nubBy removes "duplicates" as defined by a binary predicate
nubBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
nubBy f []     = []
nubBy f (x:xs) = x:(nubBy f (filter (not . f x) xs))
```

Comment: Well, you could look up the definition of nubBy.  Then substitute it into the definition of takeS above (just like you would in Algebra).

Comment: Oh I see. Ok so I'm sorry for keep asking but what if I want to take an input? Ex: takeS [(x,y)]

Comment: @user496579: it does take an input, try it out in GHCi

Comment: Right. I mean the type of takeS should be [(a,b)] instead of [(a,b)] -> [(a,b)] because my next step in the exercise is to modify the result of takeS to Just (x,y) where (x,y) is the first pair of the returning list :)

Comment: I don't follow you. If you want to take an input (in other words if you want it to be a function) it has to have an arrow (`->`) in the type. If you want a function which takes `[(a, b)]` and returns `Maybe (a, b)`, the type of that function is `[(a, b)] -> Maybe (a, b)`

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. There are actually 2 parts. I just combine them into 1 question. The first part is takeS1 :: [(a,b)] -> Maybe (a,b,b) where takeS returns a tuple containing the first conflict element a and 2 elements after the conflicting element. Ex:takeS1 [("a",1),("b",2),("b",3)] returns Just (b,2,3). The second part is takeS :: Eq a => [(a,b)] -> Maybe [(a,b)] which recursively deletes conflicting elements. Ex: takeS [("a",1),("b",2),("b",3),("c",4),("c",5)] returns Just [("a",1),("b",2),("c",4)]